# MySQLdelete all entry except last 20 for each individual

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a MySQL table having columns as below

```
chat_id     sender  receiver    msg     msg_time
```

i need a query that will execute every day to delete all messages except latest 20 messages received by each receiver.is there a single query or i need to do some code in PhP or any other programming language

Comment: If you want to execute something everyday, you could use Cronjobs

Comment: A solution could be a php script mixed with some mysql queries executed by a cronjob

Comment: i need a possible query or a programming steps to to use as Cronjob every day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query

```
select 
    *
from
(select 
    @rn:=if(@prv=receiver, @rn+1, 1) as rId,
    @prv:=receiver as receiver,
    chat_id,
    sender,
    msg,
    msg_time
from  
    tbl
join
    (select @rn:=0, @prv:='')tmp
order by 
    receiver, msg_time desc)tmp
where rid >= 20;
```

This select query will return all the records other than last 20 for each user, you can use it accordingly in your delete statement..

```
delete 
   a
from 
   tbl a
inner join 
   (select 
       @rn:=if(@prv=receiver, @rn+1, 1) as rId,
       @prv:=receiver as receiver,
       chat_id,
       sender,
       msg,
       msg_time
   from  
       tbl
   join
       (select @rn:=0, @prv:='')tmp
   order by 
       receiver, msg_time desc
   )tmp
 on 
   a.chat_id=tmp.chat_id
 where 
   tmp.rId >20
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do it using correlated subquery and without using any user variables.

```
DELETE  a
FROM    TableName a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  *, 
                    (
                        SELECT  COUNT(*)
                        FROM    tableName c
                        WHERE   c.receiver = a.receiver AND
                                c.msg_time >= a.msg_time) AS RowNumber
            FROM    TableName a
        ) b ON a.receiver = b.receiver AND
                a.msg_time = b.msg_time AND
                b.RowNumber <= 3 -- <<== change this to your desired value
WHERE   b.receiver IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8eba7/1)

the current query will remove all the records except for the 3 latest record for each `receiver` based on `msg_time`. Just change `3` to `20` to fit your needs.

Comment: +1 nice alternative but not sure its more optimal then the one from Meherzad

Answer (score 0):

If you can run this query each day (maybe with a cronjob), it should be ok.
I'm not entirely sure about the query, but it sure is a start.

```
DELETE FROM messages 
WHERE chat_id NOT IN (
    SELECT chat_id 
    FROM messages 
    GROUP BY sender 
    ORDER BY msg_time DESC 
    LIMIT 20
)
```

Comment: What I'm not sure of is the inner query. It's possible this one doesn't select 20 posts per sender but 20 post in total. You should check this.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an auto-incrementing index, you could do it in one query. Just delete everything with index < max_index - 20 ...

You will need a subquery and the max function to do it

Comment: but how  can i delete for each receiver

Comment: oh, sorry, I didn't read properly, in this case you need to modify my answer. But since a correct one has already been given, I'll not elaborate more.